# I get "undefined is not an object" whenever I try to call a ReactNativeLibrary I created inside another react native application

Tags: react-native

I am creating a react native library following [this article](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/creating-a-native-module-in-react-native-93bab0123e46) which uses the command `npm install -g react-native-create-library`. My library is very simple and all it does is pop an alert,  and only has code in the index file given below:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { RNReactNativeOgonModule } = NativeModules;

class RNReactNativeOgon {
    create() {
        Alert.alert('You need to...')
    }
}

export default new RNReactNativeOgon()
```

I then try to add this library in a react-native project by packing the library using: `npm pack`

Then I install the above-created package in the react-native application like

```
npm install C:\Users\Java\Documents\CodeHub\ReactNative\ReactNativeOgon\react-native-react-native-ogon-1.0.0.tgz
```

and then I import it into the file I want to use it in like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, Alert, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {RNReactNativeOgon} from 'react-native-react-native-ogon';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {

    const showAlert = () =>{
      RNReactNativeOgon.create();
   }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress ={showAlert} style = {styles.button}>
         <Text>Alert</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I get the error

```
> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'new_reactNativeReactNativeOgon.RNReactNativeOgon.create)
```

anytime I click the TouchableOpcaity widget that fires the function :

```
const showAlert = () =>{ 
new RNReactNativeOgon.create();
}
```

meaning `import {RNReactNativeOgon} from 'react-native-react-native-ogon';` returns an undefined object.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
import RNReactNativeOgon from 'react-native-react-native-ogon';
```

Since your library has a default export, you have to import it without the curly braces `{ }`